# Debian 6 with Smart Array 5i

Tags: debian, raid, debian-squeeze, array

I have a HP (Compaq) DL 380 G3 which I want to install Debian 6 on. It has been running Debian 5 for a long time without any problems, but now when I want to reinstall the machine to Debian 6 it can't find my RAID controller. Most likely it is too old.

How can I install Debian 6 on my server with my RAID controller? Can I somehow add these drivers to the netinst disc, and if so... how?

Comment: Is it an option to install Debian 5 and then upgrade to 6? You may find it works more or less, just that you need to stay on an older Kernel. You may also find that if you can build your own kernel (not that hard, actually) for Debian 6, then that could work too.

Comment: That would be a very good solution, the thing is that we can't find any complete DVDs for debian, only netinst cd's. I need a full install DVD. Do you have any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have to speculate, I would guess this has nothing to do with the age of your system and has more to do with Debian's decision to strip out all the modules from the kernel that have non-free firmware blobs.  I would suggest you try non-free netinst CD to do your install and see if the controller is recognized.

See:

- http://wiki.debian.org/Firmware
- http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/